# Linespread changes the m{width} cell height of NiceTabular in nicematrix

Tags: nicematrix

The sample codes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\NiceMatrixOptions{hvlines}
\linespread{1}\selectfont
linespread sets to 1.0

\begin{NiceTabular}{lr}[baseline=t]
 align & l \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\begin{NiceTabular}{b{1cm}r}[baseline=t]
 align & b \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\begin{NiceTabular}{p{1cm}r}[baseline=t]
 align & p \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\begin{NiceTabular}{m{1cm}r}[baseline=t]
 align & m \\
\end{NiceTabular}


\linespread{1.5}\selectfont
linespread sets to 1.5

\begin{NiceTabular}{lr}[baseline=t]
 align & l \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\begin{NiceTabular}{b{1cm}r}[baseline=t]
 align & b \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\begin{NiceTabular}{p{1cm}r}[baseline=t]
 align & p \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\begin{NiceTabular}{m{1cm}r}[baseline=t]
 align & m \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\linespread{2}\selectfont
linespread sets to 2

\begin{NiceTabular}{lr}[baseline=t]
 align & l \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\begin{NiceTabular}{b{1cm}r}[baseline=t]
 align & b \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\begin{NiceTabular}{p{1cm}r}[baseline=t]
 align & p \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\begin{NiceTabular}{m{1cm}r}[baseline=t]
 align & m \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

The output：

[image]

Comment: That's clearly a bug of `nicematrix`. I will try to find a solution (I'm the author of `nicematrix`).

Comment: Thank you very much. nicematrix package is very good. :-)

Comment: I have posted on CTAN a new version of `nicematrix` (v 5.19 of 2021/07/23) which solves that bug.

Comment: There are the same outputs, now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug of `nicematrix` has been corrected in the latest version of `nicematrix` (v 5.19 of 2021/07/23).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\NiceMatrixOptions{hvlines}
\linespread{1}\selectfont
linespread sets to 1.0

\begin{NiceTabular}{lr}[baseline=t]
 align & l \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\begin{NiceTabular}{b{1cm}r}[baseline=t]
 align & b \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\begin{NiceTabular}{p{1cm}r}[baseline=t]
 align & p \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\begin{NiceTabular}{m{1cm}r}[baseline=t]
 align & m \\
\end{NiceTabular}


\linespread{1.5}\selectfont
linespread sets to 1.5

\begin{NiceTabular}{lr}[baseline=t]
 align & l \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\begin{NiceTabular}{b{1cm}r}[baseline=t]
 align & b \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\begin{NiceTabular}{p{1cm}r}[baseline=t]
 align & p \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\begin{NiceTabular}{m{1cm}r}[baseline=t]
 align & m \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\linespread{2}\selectfont
linespread sets to 2

\begin{NiceTabular}{lr}[baseline=t]
 align & l \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\begin{NiceTabular}{b{1cm}r}[baseline=t]
 align & b \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\begin{NiceTabular}{p{1cm}r}[baseline=t]
 align & p \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\begin{NiceTabular}{m{1cm}r}[baseline=t]
 align & m \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]